# How to build a GDB client running on Windows to connect to a GDB server on Linux Powerpc?

Tags: linux, windows, gdb, powerpc, gdbserver

I downloaded a GDB package from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/ and built a GDB server from it to run on Linux Powerpc. But I don't know how to build a GDB that runs on Windows and that can communicate with a GDB server running on Linux Powerpc, or where to download one.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know how to build a GDB that runs on Windows and that can communicate with a GDB server running on Linux Powerpc

You need to build a cross-debugger. Usually it's something like:

```
mkdir build && cd build &&
../configure --target=powerpc-linux &&
make
```

Comment: Thanks. But I think that will just produce a GDB that runs on the same system on which it was built, i.e. x86 Linux. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @xiaokaoy You need to build it on a system on which you are intending to run it, i.e. Windows.

Comment: In that case, do I need to install anything like a cross-compiler on Windows before doing the **configure** and **make**?

Comment: @xiaokaoy You cross-compile when your build machine is different from the machine where you actually run the program, which is *not* what you are trying to do. However, it's likely that you'll need to install *some* packages GDB depends on. I've never built GDB on Windows, so I don't know what these may be. `configure` will tell you though.

Comment: Do you know what is the target name for a 32 bit x86-linux? my host is windows 64

Answer (score 0):

I managed to build a GDB that runs on Windows to debug applications on Powerpc/Linux. I used **MinGW** and the same GDB package I had used for building GDB server. In a shell offered by Mingw, I also typed commands like `configure`and `make`.

Comment: Hi how did you manage to run the GDB instance in windows. I also cross compiled gdb successfully in linux but need dependencies (some DLL files) from GCC. Did you cross compile GCC also?

Comment: @MikeF Sorry, I can't remember clearly. But I'm pretty sure I didn't cross compile GCC. I installed GCC instead in MinGW instead, I think.